# Setting value of XML leaf node

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Creating an XML document in C#.  For the leaf nodes I need to set the text/value like below:

```
<location>
    <city>Denver</city>
    <state>CO</state>
    <country>United States</country>
</location>
```

- When I'm setting the values of city, state, and country above, should
  I be using InnerText or InnerXml?
- Does that answer change if I need
  to XML encode the 5 XML illegal characters (' " < > &) with
  System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape()?
- If the value of the node is wrapped in a CDATA tag, does that
  change whether I user InnerText or InnerXml?

Comment: If you're using `.Net 3.5` or later, check out `Linq-to-XML`. It's easier to use. To answer your question on CDATA, you can put anything you want there and it will look the same in the XML file as you intend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you should use LINQ to XML for this if you can.  Here's some sample code - any XML encoding is handled for you automatically.

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

doc.Root.Element("city").Value = "London";
doc.Root.Element("state").Value = "Some value with & <> in";
doc.Root.Element("country").ReplaceNodes(new XCData("Some CDATA content with & <>"));
```

Which will give you this output:

```
<location>
  <city>London</city>
  <state>Some value with &amp; &lt;&gt; in</state>
  <country><![CDATA[Some CDATA content with & <>]]></country>
</location>
```

You can see [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4Ku4Ss) for a working demo.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers guys.  I guess I should have re-structured my question since I'm asking more for best practices vs actually doing the work.  I think I got my answer from reading MSDN though.  I should be using InnerText since InnerXml is not recommended for write operations.  Also InnerText will escape any XML illegal characters whereas InnerXml expects valid XML.